# android webview html form required fields

Tags: android, webview, required

```
<input name="question" type="text" required="required" />
```

Required inputs like sample don't work in webview.

Should i use a javascript solution for this or is there an other way to make them working in webview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android does not support required attribute in webview, you should use javascript to validate the input.

Reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation